# KeyConditionExpression error and empty error response

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Im using Lambda as my backend and im performing all the DynamoDB operations from it.

I have a user table `Users` and i want to query it via its hash-key `Username`

Using the `KeyConditionExpression` statement on my params variable but i get the following error:

> There were 2 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing >required key 'KeyConditions' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected >key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params

So yeah, i tried the following legacy statement:

```
var userQuery = {
 TableName:"Users",
 KeyConditions:{
     Username:{
          ComparisonOperator:'EQ',
          AttributeValueList:[{S:"some_username"}]
     }
 }
};
```

For some reason, i get empty errors on the query callback, which looks like this:

```
dynamo.query(userQuery,function(err,data){
  if(err) console.log("error "+JSON.stringify(err,null,2));
  else console.log("pass "+JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
});
```

I've tried literally everything, gotten to the point of desperation...

I cant seem to query any table, but i can scan and use putItem with no problem. My policy has the query parameter as well.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "my_Stmt_num",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```

In case its relevant, at the top of my handler js file im getting a reference to dynamo like this:

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
```

My whole application is 'new' meaning nothing prior than February 2015 exists, so i dont see any point in using legacy apis, as the docs say.

Comment: Could you show the actual query you are executing that is generating the errors?

Comment: var userQuery = {
        TableName:"Users",
         KeyConditionExpression:"Username = :username",
         ExpressionAttributeValues:{
             ":username":"some_username",
         }
      };

Comment: i got it to work using the legacy statement and changing the top declaration to: 
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamo = new aws.DynamoDB();       . I dont want to use the old notation, so im gonna leave the question open

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your AWS SDK associated with the document client may be out of date and does not support the new KeyConditionExpression feature. Could you please try re-installing your AWS SDK and the document SDK? Please also attach the versions you are installing if you continue to have issues after re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

Previous [DynamoDB Document SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) was deprecated, new client from standard Javascript SDK should be used from now on:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html